# Tableau - How to include Filter values to the actions and filter the target sheet

Tags: filter, action, tableau-api

I have the workbook attached in the below link.

1. I have 3 Dashboard, 1 and 2 is the source and 3 is the target. When I click on any numbers in the Dashboard 1 or 2 or even drill down the Dashboard 1 and 2 using filters the same result underlying data should come in the Dashboard 3.
2. I have a filter "Region" in Dashboard 1 and 2 and whenever I use this filter the target data is not getting filtered based on Region.
3. I don't want to make the Region filter a global one since the user may want to see different regions in dashboard 1 and 2 simultaneously.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: If there are different regions selected in 1 & 2, what should appear in 3?

Comment: Based on which Dashboard Region they are selecting the data should appear in Dashbaord 3.